# GoogleMaps - revert editable polygon to its original state (setting its path to previous state)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a simple polygon on my google map with an option to edit it. When the users edits it, he can save it, or cancel the edit. At this moment, I would like to return the polygon to the state before the edits.
I thought, it can be done with the `getPaths()` / `setPaths()` methods. But that's not working for me.

```
$(".editButton").on('click', function() {
    myPolygon.setOptions({editable: true});
    originalPath = myPolygon.getPaths();
});

$(".cancelButton").on('click', function() {
    myPolygon.setOptions({editable: false});
    myPolygon.setPaths(originalPath);
});
```

I tried setting the path also via the `setOptions()` method, but that doesnt change the path back to its original shape either.

Is there some another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myPolygon.getPaths()` is returning a reference to the "live" paths in the polygon, it gets updated when you edit the polygon.

One option would be to copy the path (or paths if you have more than one).

```
originalPath = [];
for (var i=0; i<myPolygon.getPath().getArray().length; i++) {
  originalPath.push(myPolygon.getPath().getArray()[i]);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/4yekmot5/)

**code snippet:**

```js
"use strict";

// This example creates a simple polygon representing the Bermuda Triangle.
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {
      lat: 24.886,
      lng: -70.268,
    },
    mapTypeId: "terrain",
  }); // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.

  const triangleCoords = [{
      lat: 25.774,
      lng: -80.19,
    },
    {
      lat: 18.466,
      lng: -66.118,
    },
    {
      lat: 32.321,
      lng: -64.757,
    },
    {
      lat: 25.774,
      lng: -80.19,
    },
  ]; // Construct the polygon.

  const myPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#FF0000",
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map
  });

  var originalPath;
  $(".editButton").on('click', function() {
    myPolygon.setOptions({editable: true});
    originalPath = [];
    for (var i=0; i<myPolygon.getPath().getArray().length; i++) {
      originalPath.push(myPolygon.getPath().getArray()[i]);
    }
  });

  $(".cancelButton").on('click', function() {
    myPolygon.setOptions({editable: false});
    myPolygon.setPath(originalPath);
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 90%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Polygon</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap"
      defer
    ></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
  <input type="button" class="editButton" value="edit"/>
  <input type="button" class="cancelButton" value="cancel"/>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Making a copy of the array was a way to go. Thank you